# Can I create an if formula to round decimals with differents statements?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I'm having trouble trying to create the formula to round numbers with an if function. I need to round decimals between 5 different statements:

- If a number has decimals between 0.1 and 0.5 rounddown to 0.
- If a number has decimals between 0.6 and 0.29 round to 0.25.
- If a number has decimals between 0.30 and 0.55 round to 0.50.
- If a number has decimals between 0.56 and 0.80 round to 0.75.
- If a number has decimals between 0.76 and 0.99 round to 1.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Would you please clarify some aspects of your question: you say _If a number has decimals_, so do you mean that you're only dealing with values between 0 and 1, can this be any number; e.g. 4.23, 6.95, etc. Second, there is a problem in the sequence of decimals values (maybe just a typo). "0.1 and 0.5": "0.5" must be wrong because the next level = 0.29. "0.6 and 0.29": "0.6" must be wrong because it is greater than 0.29". "0.76 and 0.99": do you mean "0.8 to 0.99"? Third, please give some examples of how a number should be rounded.

Comment: Please share a link to a spreadsheet with realistic sample data already entered, as well as your hand-entered results for what you'd like to see the formula returning. I agree with Tedinoz: your sets are off. I think you mean something like {0.01 - 0.05, 0.06 - 0.29, etc.}

Comment: You are right. The secuence is:

Answer (score 1):

Use `ifs()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  A2 < 0.01, na(), 
  A2 <= 0.05, 0, 
  A2 <= 0.29, 0.25, 
  A2 <= 0.55, 0.5, 
  A2 <= 0.8, 0.75, 
  A2 <= 1, 1, 
  true, na() 
)
```

Comment: The OP's sequence of percentages is topsy turvy, but I wonder whether the first condition shouldn't be `A2<0.01`?

Comment: Edited the answer.